# Express.Router, body-parser and post request body

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, express-router

I am trying to seperate my routes using express.Router and testing some post requests with Postman.
Doing a post request to /test without using router body-parser works fine and i can see the body.
Doing the exact same request to /posts which is using Router gives me undefined for the body.
I call body-parser middleware before the posts router. Is there something i am missing?

My express server file:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

const postsRoute = require('./routes/posts');
app.use('/posts', postsRoute);

app.post('/test',(req,res)=>{    
    console.log('Add post:',req.body);
});


app.listen(3000);
```

My posts router file:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.send('Posts');
});

router.post('/',(res,req)=>{
    console.log('Add post:',req.body);
});

module.exports = router;
```

My postman request with Content-type header set to application/json:
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPas0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as i posted the question i found out what that i wrote req and res in the wrong order. 1 hour and a half for a silly mistake! Have a nide day everyone!